# Nx & Angular: resolve dependency in module

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

My plan was to use the NgRx related modules (store, effects, devtools, etc.) in a library module, not in the app-module.

The NgRx related modules are imported into the libs/.../shell-module, which in turn is imported into the app-module.

## The problem

I would like to provide the environment.production variable in my libs, but I have no idea how to get it in the shell-module without using a relative/absolute import path.

`libs/.../shell.module.ts`:

```js
import { environment } from '../../../../../../../apps/test-app/src/environments/environment';

imports:[
...
!environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []
...
]
```

## Questions

1. Is it not possible to resolve the environment.production variable in an Angular module?
    I know how to inject stuff into components, but how do you inject it into modules?
    The .forRoot() config trick didn't work, because the imports array in the module decorator is out of scope of the module class.
2. is there another way to do this without tight coupling the environment.ts file and my libs modules?
3. Defining an '@' path for environment.ts in tsconfig.json, and then importing it into the module still counts as tight coupling ... right?

Comment: Hi, I am new to Nx and found your SO question from the Nx Github issue page. If I may ask, what are the advantages of importing your env variables from a module as opposed to using the InjectionToken method that Victor suggested in the Github issue page?

Comment: I would just add a provider (InjectionToken) in the library `ANGULAR_ENVIRONMENT`, which is exposed through the `public-api.ts`, and in the `app.module.ts` have a provider `{ provide: ANGULAR_ENVIRONMENT, useValue: 'production' }`. Inject this provider anywhere in your library

Answer (score 0):

for this I'd generally recommend moving the environment configuration down into a library as well.

For example, you may have `libs/shared/env/environment.*.ts`, or `libs/domain/env/environment.*.ts`. You'll need to update the build steps for your app to ensure that fileReplacements is setup to handle these. Then in your app you can use `import {environment} from '@company/shared/eng'`.

This would look a little different if using buildable libs, since you'd want to handle the fileReplacements in the libraries build definition.

Comment: Hi Craigory, I thought about doing that. However, would this not be "breaking the recommended Angular/Nx project structure"? And possibly lead to unnecessary problems in the long run?

Comment: I don't think this would be breaking the structure any more than any other core shared libraries would.

Comment: I did that and I'm getting this error: "Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project. Use "./path/to/file" instead of import from...". The error is present even after restarting the ESLint server.

Comment: @PaxForce Was your issue fixed related to  "Use "./path/to/file" instead of import from" error?